# Output a Python dictionary as a table with a custom format

Tags: python, formatting

I have a Python directory containing some `str: int` key-value pairs, and my goal is to display that data in a tabular format.

I am unable to use the `tabulate` module because it seems that it cannot display data *exactly* as is required by the project sponsors (and as far as I know you cannot customise the formats), so I'm having to hand crank the simplest solution I can find.

#### Example of desired output

```shell
Name        Passes
------------------
Name One         7
Name Two         1
Name Three      35
------------------
Total           43
```

#### Code

While the task is pretty simple, the code is pretty verbose. Is this the best way to do this, or is there a better way that would be more efficient (but still without using `tabulate`)?

```py
def print_table(data: dict, spacer_length: int=2) -> None:
    '''Print the given data dictionary in a table format.
    
    Arguments:
        data (dict): The data dictionary to ouput.
        spacer_length (int=2): The number of spaces between each column.
        Minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 10.
    '''

    # Transform the `pass_count` dict into and array of columns.
    # At the same time, add the required headers and footers.
    cols = [
        ['Name'] + list(data) + ['Total'],
        ['Passes'] + list(data.values()) + [sum([v for v in data.values()])]]

    # Find the length of the longest item in each column.
    col_widths = [max(len(str(v)) for v in c) for c in cols]

    # Format items in each column to the length of the longest item.
    cols = [[f'{v:{col_widths[i]}}' for v in c] for i, c in enumerate(cols)]

    # Pop the column headers and footers.
    headers = [c.pop(0) for c in cols]
    footers = [c.pop() for c in cols]

    # Construct the separator.
    spacer_length = min((max((1, int(spacer_length))), 10))
    spacer = ' ' * spacer_length
    seperator = '-' * (sum(col_widths) + ((len(col_widths) - 1) * spacer_length))

    rows = [spacer.join(list(row)) for row in zip(cols[0], cols[1])]
    print(spacer.join(headers), seperator,'\n'.join(rows),
        seperator, spacer.join(footers), sep='\n')


pass_count = {
    'Name One': 7,
    'Name Two': 1,
    'Name Three': 35,
}

print_table(pass_count)
```

Comment: Seems pretty OK? Why is there a maximum on spacer length?

Comment: It *appears* that you want the first column left-aligned and the second column right-aligned. But that outcome is an artifact of Python's default formatting behavior when given strings vs numbers. If your counts were to include a large number (wider than second column header), the second column would end up having a left-aligned header and right-aligned numbers. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @Reinderien, No technical reason, but I thought that was a good idea to prevent the gap between columns from being too large and wasting terminal space.

Comment: @Fmc, that's a good point regarding the header, although extremely unlikely in this case due to the data I'll be outputting. I have no particular requirement to output numbers right-aligned, and as you say the only reason they are aligned that way is because Python did it automatically for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further reading, it turns out that it is possible to do everything that is needed using the `tabulate` module.

As pointed out in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285837/67268), it is possible to add a custom table format. Sadly the `TableFormat` object is a `namedtuple`, making it immutable, therefore it's required to create an entirely new format rather than update an existing one that is close to what is needed.

The other piece of the puzzle is the `SEPARATING_LINE`, which means a separator and then the footer can simply be appended to the table data. See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/72).

```py
from tabulate import tabulate, TableFormat, Line, DataRow, SEPARATING_LINE

def main() -> None:
    pass_count = {
        'Name One': 7,
        'Name Two': 1,
        'Name Three': 35,
    }
    print(report(pass_count))

def report(data: dict) -> None:

    # Create a custom table format.
    tablefmt = TableFormat(
        lineabove=Line('', '-', '', ''),
        linebelowheader=Line('', '-', '', ''),
        linebetweenrows=None,
        linebelow=Line('', '-', '', ''),
        headerrow=DataRow('', '', ''),
        datarow=DataRow('', '', ''),
        padding=0,
        with_header_hide=['lineabove', 'linebelow']
    )

    # Make the data dictionary a list and append the separator and footer.
    data_list = list(data.items())
    data_list.append(SEPARATING_LINE)
    data_list.append(('Total', sum(data.values())))

    return tabulate(data_list, headers=('Name', 'Passes'), tablefmt=tablefmt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 4):

> I am unable to use the tabulate module because it seems that it cannot
> display data exactly as is required by the project sponsors (and as
> far as I know you cannot customise the formats)

That sounds like a challenge to me.
Let's see if I can challenge this assumption.

You can definitely customize the format beyond using the canned formats available out of the box. For example here I have customized the "simple" built-in format after having a look at the source code of the package. I also added a supplementary line to your dict to compute the subtotals.

```
from tabulate import tabulate, TableFormat, Line, DataRow

pass_count = {
    'Name One': 7,
    'Name Two': 1,
    'Name Three': 35
}

pass_count.update({"Total": sum(pass_count.values())})

my_format = TableFormat(
        lineabove=Line("", "-", "", ""),
        linebelowheader=Line("", "-", "", ""),
        linebetweenrows=None,
        linebelow=Line("", "-", "", ""),
        headerrow=DataRow("", "", ""),
        datarow=DataRow("", "", ""),
        padding=0,
        with_header_hide=["lineabove", "linebelow"]
    )
print(tabulate(pass_count.items(), headers=["Name", "Passes"], colalign=("left", "right"), tablefmt=my_format))
```

Output:

```
Name        Passes
------------------
Name One         7
Name Two         1
Name Three      35
Total           43
```

We are almost there. But we are still lacking the footer separator to match the desired output. tabulate does not seem to have have any provisions for **footers** and I don't see a quick an easy way right now.

So, to address your own implementation:

My issue with your `print_table` function is that it lacks **flexibility**:

- you have **hardcoded** the header names. You could emulate the tabulate functionality to grab the headers from the dataset, or provide them manually as function arguments
- it only works with dicts
- and even if you allowed other data structures like lists, you are only handling two columns
- your docstring says:

> spacer_length (int=2): The number of spaces between each column.
> Minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 10.

so you have added further constraints, but I don't see any benefit of doing so.

That function looks like a serious **regression** when compared to the relative flexibility of tabulate.

Perhaps I would have created a function with a **signature** that is similar to tabulate, even without implementing all the available function arguments at once.

Instead of `list(data)` you could do: `data.keys()`, just like you use `data.values()` thereafter.

I would be strongly tempted to **fork** the tabulate project to implement table **footers**, as I already use that package in several projects of mine but I haven't needed the footer functionality so far. That makes perfect sense, if we can have headers, why not footers.
Maybe somebody has already done just that, I would search in Github for example.

There are alternatives like prettytable, maybe there is one package somewhere that does what you want.

In fact you could cheat a little and settle for tabulate. It returns a string, that you are free to manipulate further. Either call tabulate twice, or insert the missing delimiter line manually. This is trivial to do, although it lacks elegance. But that would not make the code excessively obscure or complicated at all.

On the other hand, your `print_table` function does not return anything: it prints directly, thus removing flexibility. What if we want to add enhancements or colorize the table for example?

Typo: seperator should be separator.

Comment: There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/69) on Github but no indication of any work on it...

Comment: @Kate, thanks for your detailed reply. You are right that my solution lacks flexibility, mainly because in this case I need it for a specific task - so that's why it only accepts a `dict` (i.e. two columns), because I know the `dict` contains data as key-value pairs containing the Names and Passes that I wish to display. I have however now made a change so that the headers can be passed to the function, to make possible future use easier. With regards to the `spacer`, this again is with possible future use in mind, but to be honest I'll probably just hardcode that to `2`.

Comment: @Kate, thanks again for your help. I have updated my code taking in to account most of your comments. It's no doubt still a regression compared to using `tabulate()`, but better than it was.

Comment: @Kate, turns out it is possible to do everything I need with `tabulate()`. It's not exactly a footer, but it is possible to add a separating line at any position within the table data. I've added [another answer here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285899/67268).

Answer (score 3):

**An ill-advised transpose**. Your original implementation transposes the data
into columns (to help the width computation) but most of the table-building
work is simpler with the original row orientation. The result is some awkward
hoop-jumping: popping values to get headers/footers; and zipping the columns
back together to build the lines. It seems easier to transpose purely for width
calculation but otherwise work with the row-wise data.

**Many built-ins accept iterables**. Your calculation of the total is like
this: `sum([v for v in data.values()])`. That has two unneeded parts: (1) the
list is not needed because `sum()` accepts any iterable, including generator
expressions; (2) the compression isn't needed since the values themselves
are iterable.

**Don't mix printing and algorithm**. And especially don't
implement your algorithm via `print()`.
Making an aligned table involves many
algorithmic details. Keep that kind of code separate from side effects like
printing. This point is fundamental and, at least in my experience, one of the
keys to evolving one's software design instincts from the level of good (your
current implementations are reasonable and easy to follow) to something better.

**Make the alignment explicit**. As discussed in the comments, your
right-aligned outcome in the second column involves a bit of luck.

**Consider whether you want greater simplicity or power**. Based on your
question and comments, it seems like you have a narrow use case: print a dict
of counts as an aligned table with a specific style. I don't know the whole
context, but sometimes it's wise to emphasize code simplicity rather than
generality and features. Here's an approach that aims to cover only the use
case at hand as simply and clearly as possible.

```python
def main():
    counts = {'One': 7, 'Two': 1, 'Three': 35, 'Four': 9999999}
    print(dict_to_table(counts))

def dict_to_table(d):
    # Define table rows.
    header = ('Name', 'Passes')
    footer = ('Total', sum(d.values()))
    rows = [header] + list(d.items()) + [footer]

    # Compute column widths.
    widk = max(len(k) for k, _ in  rows)
    widv = max(len(str(v)) for _, v in  rows)

    # Build table lines.
    fmt = '{:<{}}  {:>{}}'
    lines = [fmt.format(k, widk, v, widv) for k, v in rows]

    # Add dividers and return.
    div = '\n' + ('-' * (widk + widv + 2))
    lines[0] += div
    lines[-2] += div
    return '\n'.join(lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on suggestions from others in comments and answers, I have amended my code.

- Header names are no longer hardcoded, and can be passed to the `print_table()` function. Additionally, the footer can be passed in the same way. However, I haven't gone as far as allowing `firstrow`, `lastrow` etc. for specifying headers because in my use case I don't need that. Note also that there is a restriction in that the length of the iterable representing headers and footers must be the same length as all items in the table data. For example, you can't have three columns of data but not have three headers/footers.
- The `print_table()` function now accepts any iterable, such as an `list` or a `tuple`. This makes it more scalable, though in actually I've gone the other way in one respect because it won't accept a `dict` any more.
- There is no longer a limit on the number of columns.
- The restriction on `spacer_length` has been removed.
- Typos have been fixed (hopefully!).
- Explicit column alignment is now possible. Unlike headers and footers, alignment can be set for only some columns. by passing a short iterable (e.g. `('right',)`). If the column that needs to be explicitly aligned is not the first, an empty string can be passed so that the Python default alignment for that data type is used (e.g. `('', 'centre')`). I'm not entirely happy with how it works currently, but for the time I have today that's the best I could do.

One thing I haven't changed is that `print_table()` still prints the table rather than return it. That's fine for my use case right now, and something that I can fairly easily change in the future if needs be.

````py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def print_table(data: Iterable, headers: Iterable=None, footers: Iterable=None,
    colalign: Iterable=(), spacer_length: int=2) -> None:

    ALIGN_LEFT = ['left', '<']
    ALIGN_RIGHT = ['right', '>']
    ALIGN_CENTRE = ['centre', 'center', '^']

    def width(column: tuple) -> int:
        '''Return the length of the longest item in the column.'''
        return max(map(len, map(str, column)))

    def alignment(term: str) -> str:
        '''Return the alignment '''
        return ('<' if term.lower() in ALIGN_LEFT
            else '>' if term.lower() in ALIGN_RIGHT
            else '^' if term.lower() in ALIGN_CENTRE else '')

    # Ensure the data is a list and insert the header and footer.
    data_list = list(data)
    data_list.insert(0, headers) if headers is not None else None
    data_list.append(footers) if footers is not None else None

    # Find the length of the longest value in each column.
    widths = list(map(width, zip(*data_list)))

    # Get column alignments.
    aligns = [alignment(colalign[i]) if len(colalign) > i else ''
        for i, _ in enumerate(zip(*data_list))]

    # Make the spacer and the separator.
    spacer = ' ' * spacer_length
    separator = '-' * (sum(widths) + ((len(widths) - 1) * spacer_length))

    # Join date to make the rows for table output.
    rows = [spacer.join(f'{v:{aligns[i]}{widths[i]}}' for i, v 
        in enumerate(r)) for r in data_list]

    # Insert separators for the headers and footers.
    rows.insert(1, separator) if headers is not None else None
    rows.insert(-1, separator) if footers is not None else None

    print(*rows, sep='\n')
```
````